# How to align two figures with different labels?

Tags: matlab-figure

These are two figures in my paper. Apparently, the two axes are not in alignment. How can I make sure that two figures generated independently align with each other? The problem is that the two figures have different labels and different ticklabels. That makes the positions of the axes different.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For each subplot, find the x/y/width/height. Then adjust the second (or both) to be the same height and the same "y"

```
get(gca,'position')
set(gca, 'position', [0.1300    0.15    0.3347  0.3412]) %x y width height, dummy numbers
```

Comment: It is not a subplot！The two figures are generated independently.

Comment: @jmzhang That's fine, the above idea should work for independent figures, too. The idea is that you get/set the position of both plots, whether they are subplots or regular plots.